# What part/actuator do you think they used

Tags: motor, components, actuator

At around 2:20 in this video there is an interesting use of electronics. You can watch the video but in short there are these little spoon creatures that pop out from behind a covering. The speed at which they react is proportional to sound. My question is what kind of actuator do you think they used for the movement? Sorry if this is a dumb question, I am not mechanically inclined.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FQdQhV1yjfc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I can see ordinary RC servos there. It looks like the motors are those grey metal cylindrical things with the orange and green stickers.

[image: Pygmies]

Something like this maybe?

[image: Stepper motor]

It's a stepper motor.

Answer (score 0):

They show the back of the panel a little later in the video; they're just ordinary RC servos.